# SQL Server Incorrect syntax near '(' in recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am trying to convert a IBM db2 query to a SQL Server query. I am not very familiar with WITH AS construct.

The db2 query (which works) is:

```
with ZoneList (id, name, parent_name, parent_id, level) as 
(select id, name, '', parent_id, 1 as level 
from products.zones where id = 1 
union all 
select z.id, z.name, l.name, z.parent_id, level + 1 
from products.zones z, ZoneList l
where z.parent_id = l.id) 
select id, name || ' (' || parent_name || ')' as description 
from ZoneList
where level = 4 
order by ZoneList.name
```

and my SQL Server version is:

```
with ZoneList (id, name, cast((parent_name) as varchar(45)), parent_id, 
level) as 
(select id, name, cast(('') as varchar(45)), parent_id, 1 as level 
from products.zones where id = 1 
union all 
select z.id, z.name, cast((l.name) as varchar(45)), z.parent_id, level + 1 
from products.zones z, ZoneList l 
where z.parent_id = l.id) 
select id, name + ' (' + parent_name + ')' as description 
from ZoneList 
where level = 4 
order by ZoneList.name
```

I have added casts in order to avoid incompatibility type error, but now I am getting syntax error near '('.

Comment: instead of `cast((parent_name) as varchar(45))` in the first line, just use `parent_name`-- `with ZoneList (id, name, parent_name, parent_id, 
level) as `.  you're saying what the column names will be, so you don't need the type declaration or the cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with ZoneList (id, name, parent_name, parent_id, level)
as (
    select id
        , name
        , cast('' as varchar(45))
        , parent_id
        , 1 as level
    from products.zones
    where id = 1

    union all

    select z.id
        , z.name
        , cast(l.name as varchar(45))
        , z.parent_id
        , level + 1
    from products.zones z
        inner join ZoneList l 
            on z.parent_id = l.id
    )
select id
    , name + ' (' + parent_name + ')' as description
from ZoneList
where level = 4
order by ZoneList.name
```

You don't need any explicit casts in the first line, because in the first line you enumerate the columns of the CTE, you don't define their datatype or size etc.

You might even totally remove the column enumeration at the top of the CTE, as long as you alias every column in your CTE, like:

```
;with ZoneList
as (
    select id
        , name
        , cast('' as varchar(45)) as [parent_name]
        , parent_id
        , 1 as level
    from products.zones
    where id = 1

    union all

    select z.id
        , z.name
        , cast(l.name as varchar(45))  as [parent_name]
        , z.parent_id
        , level + 1
    from products.zones z
        inner join ZoneList l 
            on z.parent_id = l.id
    )
select id
    , name + ' (' + parent_name + ')' as description
from ZoneList
where level = 4
order by ZoneList.name
```

Comment: I would also suggest changing the implicit join to an explicit one.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Improved

Answer (score 3):

The column list for the [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is not where you would cast that value.

```
with ZoneList  (id, name, parent_name, parent_id, level) as (
select 
    id
  , name
  , cast(('') as varchar(45)) as parent_name
  , parent_id
  , 1 as level 
from products.zones where id = 1 

union all 

select 
    z.id
  , z.name
  , cast((l.name) as varchar(45)) as parent_name
  , z.parent_id
  , level + 1 
from products.zones z
  inner join ZoneList l 
    on z.parent_id = l.id
) 
select 
    id
  , name + ' (' + parent_name + ')' as description 
from ZoneList 
where level = 4 
order by ZoneList.name
```

Comment: I would also suggest changing the implicit join to an explicit one.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Good catch